# AspectJ - How to catch constructor call also for subclasses?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have an abstract class `Foo`.

I want to have a compile error if I create a new instance of a concrete class that extends Foo outside an Aspect named `Bar`.

I tried this:

```
public pointcut errorcall(): call(Foo.new(..)) && !within(Bar);
declare error: errorcall():"Error: You must use Bar creation methods!";
```

But it doesn't catch the subclasses of `Foo`.

If I declare the pointcut as:

```
public pointcut errorcall(): call(ConcreteFoo.new(..)) && !within(Bar);
```

It catches the ConcreteFoo creation outside Bar, but I would like to intercept every subclass of Foo.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MyClass+` notation also grabs subclasses. This information can be found in any AspectJ tutorial, e.g. [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html):

```java
public pointcut errorcall():
  call(Foo+.new(..)) && !within(Bar);
```